# Adjust django forms - Comment Form CSS

Tags: css, django

I have inserted a following command form to my template:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% get_comment_form for object as form %}
    <form action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.comment }}
    {{ form.honeypot }}
    {{ form.content_type }}
    {{ form.object_pk }}
    {{ form.timestamp }}
    {{ form.security_hash }}
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url 'object_detail_view' object.id %}" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add comment" id="id_submit" />
    </form>
{% else %}
    <p>Please <a href="{% url 'auth_login' %}">log in</a> to leave a comment.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Could anyone advice what is the best method of change style of {{form.comment}} that displays only textarea wihout id or class. {{form.comment}} is defined  in the library so there is no direct access to change its style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this very same problem in a project I had and found really usefule [`django-widget-tweaks`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks).

This library allows you to modify the class of the widgets of your form from the template through filters this way:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{{ form.comment|add_class:"comment-style"}}
```

That includes the class=`comment-style` to your `form.comment` widget which is a nice decoupled way to style individual fields in a form within the template.

Besides the `class` attribute it also let you do some more individual modification as you may see in their project website.

Hope this helps!